# Gulp doesn't notice my file changes

Tags: node.js, gulp, browserify

I'm working on a project with a few others. While they get Gulp to work, it doesn't seem to work on my computer, even through our code is identical.

When I write the 'gulp' command, I get this:

```
[10:51:17] Starting 'browserify'...
[10:51:19] Finished 'browserify' after 2.37 s
[10:51:19] Starting 'default'...
[10:51:19] Finished 'default' after 17 μs
```

But when I save the changes in the files Gulp is suppose to be watching, the 'update' event doesnt seem to be triggered.

Here is the Gulp file

```
var gulp        = require("gulp"),
jest        = require("gulp-jest"),
source      = require('vinyl-source-stream'),
browserify  = require('browserify'),
watchify    = require('watchify'),
reactify    = require('reactify');
require("harmonize")();

var paths = {
   scripts: "src/**/*.js",
   tests: "__tests__"
};

gulp.task("jest", function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.tests).pipe(jest({
        scriptPreprocessor: "preprocessor.js",
        unmockedModulePathPatterns: [
            "../node_modules/react"
        ],
        testPathIgnorePatterns: [
            "node_modules",
            "spec/support"
        ],
        moduleFileExtensions: [
            "js",
            "json",
            "react"
        ]
    }));
});

gulp.task('browserify', function() {
    var bundler = browserify({
        entries: ['./src/js/TopLevel.js'],
        transform: [reactify],
        debug: true,
        cache: {}, packageCache: {}, fullPaths: true
    });
    var watcher  = watchify(bundler);

    return watcher
    .on('update', function () { // When any files update
        var updateStart = Date.now();
        console.log('Updating!');
        watcher.bundle() // Create new bundle that uses the cache for high performance
        .pipe(source('main.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/assets/js'));
        console.log('Updated!', (Date.now() - updateStart) + 'ms');
    })
    .bundle() // Create the initial bundle when starting the task
    .pipe(source('main.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/assets/js'));
});

gulp.task("watch", function() {
  gulp.watch("src/**/*.js", ["jest"]);
  gulp.watch("__tests__/*.js", ["jest"]);
});

gulp.task("default", ["browserify"]);
```

However, I don't think there is anything wrong with the code, as it works for my other team members.

Any help and comments are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
gulp.task("watch", function() {
  gulp.watch("./src/**/*.js", ["jest"]);
  gulp.watch("./__tests__/*.js", ["jest"]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only running `gulp` in the command line the watch task will not trigger since the default task is only running browserify, just change your default task to this.

`gulp.task("default", ["browserify", "watch"]);`